# Understanding the distinction between "SENTRY_DSN" and "SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN" environment variables in Laravel's Sentry package

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, sentry, dsn

What is the difference between the "SENTRY_DSN" and "SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN" environment variables in the Sentry package within Laravel? Need clarification or guidance to a reliable source explaining their distinctions.

Demystifying the similarity or dissimilarity between "SENTRY_DSN" and "SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN" environment variables in Laravel's Sentry package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the changelog for the getsentry/sentry-laravel package, they changed their .env variable from `SENTRY_DSN` to `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN` in version 0.9.0.

The `SENTRY_DSN` environment variable is used by the base `getsentry/sentry-php` package. In order to avoid the collision with the base package, and to allow the Laravel package to be in control of the DSN name, the Laravel package renamed their environment variable.

However, the Laravel package will use the base `SENTRY_DSN` environment variable if the `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN` environment variable isn't defined.

If you're only using sentry through the Laravel package, you only need `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN`. If you're using the base sentry package outside of Laravel, you'll need `SENTRY_DSN`.